# RDLC ReportViewer First Load is Slow on Web Page

Tags: performance, rdlc

Getting slow loading time at first RDLC report load on web form using ReportViewer control.
Tested on both .NET Frameworks 4.5 & 4.5.1.
Is there a trick to lower this first time loading time?